# Java - Calculate How Many Elements have x property

Tags: java

I have a very basic class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ApplicationType")
public class ApplicationType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long applicationTypeId;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "applicationType")
    private Set<Application> applications; 

   // getters setters
  }
```

And a Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/application/types")
public ResponseEntity<?> getApplicationTypes() {
    List<ApplicationType> applicationTypes = applicationTypeRepository.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(applicationTypes, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My DB has 100000 applications returned by findAll();, `50000 of applicationType 1` and `50000 of applicationType 2`

**How can I easily extract how many applications of each type exists without crashing my API? My solution was to loop all the applications and checking their type but this is VERY BAD**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Spring Data (> 1.7.1) and in your `CrudRepository<Application, "Primary ID Type of Application Table">` have a method like:

```
 Long countByApplicationType(String applicationType);
```